# Tricky MySQL / PHP data issue: calculating totals from sparse data with carry-forward

Tags: php, mysql

Ok, I'll do my best to explain the problem here:

The scenario is that we're trying to keep track of currently on hand inventory for items that are continuously changing in quantity.

The way it's set up is that any time an item changes in quantity, a row is written to a MySQL table 'tracking' that records the item SKU, the latest quantity, and a timestamp.

For example:

```
Dec. 4, 2010 --- Item #12 --- 200 
Dec. 5, 2010 --- Item #33 --- 150
Dec. 8, 2010 --- Item #12 --- 50
```

The problem is that we want to answer the question -- how many total items do we have at any point in time?

This is harder than it looks because of the sparse data problem.

Let's say on Dec. 4, 2010, we had 200 of item #12
Then on Dec. 8, 2010, we had 50 of that same item (item #12)
Meanwhile, on Dec. 5, 2010, we had 150 of item #33

On Dec 4, 5, and 8, how many total items do we have?
The right answer is 200 total on Dec. 4, 350 on Dec. 5, and 200 on Dec. 8. How do we get those numbers? Well, we have to carry forward the quantities of items from one date to the next. Even if we don't specify how much we have of that item on the next day, we have to assume that we had as much as we did the previous day.

So, Dec. 4, we had 200 of Item #12, and so on Dec. 5, we still have 200 of Item #12, on top of which we now have 150 of Item #33. This yields 350 on Dec. 5. Then on Dec. 8, we still have 150 of Item #33, but just 50 of Item #12, yielding just 200 items.

The query should return these results for the above data:

```
Dec. 4, 2010: 200 items
Dec. 5, 2010: 350 items
Dec. 8, 2010: 200 items
```

The tricky issue is that there might be thousands of items... this significantly complicates the MYSQL and PHP operation.

I'm looking for an optimal solution here that makes the best use of MYSQL and PHP to solve this problem. Temp tables could work as could jamming data in a big PHP associative array, but I have a feeling there's a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your table is called `log` and has three fields, `item`, `ts` (time stamp), and `quantity`, **and that `quantity` contains deltas instead of totals** (as recommended by Cfreak):

```
set @total = 0;
select ts, c, @total := @total + c from 
(select ts, sum(quantity) c from log group by ts order by ts) days;
```

Comment: Will this give a sum by date as per the above and carry forward items from previous dates? When I run a version of the above, it seems to provide a single sum number, which doesn't make sense in my context since the sum changes by date.

Comment: On second thought, you really should consider logging deltas instead of absolute values, as Cfreak suggested. Otherwise, there is no efficient way to carry a sum.

Comment: Okay, I've now edited my answer, but it now requires you to log deltas.

Answer (score 0):

I think a better way would be to update the tracking table with the number of items changed. For instance in your example instead of the second entry saying item #12 has 50, you would say it has -150 because that is the change from the previous operation.

You could have the script that updates this table take that into account. Get the total number of items using `SUM` and then update with the change.

```
SELECT SUM(quantity) FROM tracking WHERE item=12;
```

(get the value of that query)

```
$change_value = $new_quantity - $quantity_from_db;
```

Then update the tracking table with the $change_value;

To get a report the query is the same as @benisu's. You could do it by date by using a range rather than selecting a particular date. For example get your snapshot on December 5:

```
SELECT item, SUM(quantity) FROM tracking WHERE date <= '2010-12-05' GROUP BY item
```

Hope that helps.

EDIT: I see you want them returned by date and total items. Unfortunately I don't believe you can do that in a single query because you have to tell MySQL to add the values together over a range. Grouping by date will give you a snapshot only. Your best bet would be to loop through a range of dates and then issue a query for each one:

```
$array_of_dates = array('2010-12-05', '2010-12-08', '2010-12-11');
foreach( $array_of_dates as $date ) {
    $query = "SELECT SUM(quantity) FROM tracking WHERE date <= '$date'"; // don't use this unless your date input is static or sanitized!
    // your database layer of choice here to execute the query
    echo "$date: $quantity_from_query";
}
```

Comment: Not sure how this would give the results of the query (as edited) above. If I have -150 on Dec. 8 for Item #12, what would the query show for Dec. 5? It should show 350 -- the query is querying across all items, not a specific one.

Comment: Tnx for the edit! But even in this version, won't it just sum all the items together -- for example, on Dec. 8, it will add all the previous quantities together, even tho Item #12 actually went down in qty. This will give a sum of 400 for Dec. 8, when the answer should be 200, no?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your question completely, from what I gather so far you want a sum of all items counts for each date? If so, that's easily handled within MySQL using group by and sum(). I am not sure what your schema looks like, so here is my wag:

SELECT sum(item_quantity) as item_quantity_sum, date FROM items GROUP BY date

Comment: This doesn't work because on any specific date, you only have data for a particular item... but the total of what you actually have is carried forward from quantities on previous dates. For example, if I had 4 apples on Monday, and I ask "how many total fruits do I have?", I'll get 4 for Monday. If I add an orange on Tuesday, the answer is now "5 Fruits on Tuesday". But I can't enter a new row to repeat that I have 4 apples on Tuesday. I just want to specify 4 apples on Monday, 1 orange on Tuesday, and if I then have 0 apples on Wednesday, I want the sums to be 4 on Mon, 5 on Tues, and 1 Weds.